# modrewrite sometimes reflects the url, and sometimes doesn't

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Sometimes I DO want the URL change to be reflected, and other times I want it to silently serve a document.

Let me describe the structure

```
public_html (root of A.com)
- .htaccess (For domain A.com) [call it .htaccess A for ease]
↳ B (root of B.com)
  - .htaccess (For Domain B.com) [call it .htaccess B for ease]
  - index.html
  ↳ subfolder
    - rest_api.php
↳ C (root of C.B.com)
  - .htaccess (For Domain C.B.com) [call it .htaccess C for ease]
  - index.php
↳ D (root of D.B.com)
  - .htaccess (For Domain D.B.com) [call it .htaccessD for ease]
  - rest_api.php
```

In this order...

1. A.com/subfolder/(stuff) to serve D.B.com/(stuff)
2. B.com/subfolder/(stuff) to serve D.B.com/(stuff)
3. all HTTP to become HTTPS
4. A.com/%{REQUEST_URI} to redirect to B.com/%{REQUEST_URI}
5. B.com to default to B.com/index.html
6. C.B.com to default to C.B.com/index.php

.htaccess A

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Turn on the rewrite engine
  RewriteEngine On

  # If %{HTTPS} == "off"
  # Make it go to https://host/uri, permanently (R=301)
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

  # If the host name contains "A", not case sensitive (nc)
  # Make it go to https://www.B.com/uri, permanently (R=301), and stop (L)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (A)+ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.B.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess B

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Turn on the rewrite engine
  RewriteEngine On

  # If the file we want from B.com doesn't exist
  # Make it go to www.B.com/index.html, permanently (R=301)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* https://www.B.com/index.html [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess C

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Turn on the rewrite engine
  RewriteEngine On

  # If the file we want from C.B.com doesn't exist
  # Make it go to C.B.com/index.html, permanently (R=301)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* https://C.B.com/index.php [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Some helpful notes...

1. I know that the 'permanently' is client side, not server side...
2. The PHP enforces a HTTPS connection, so I do not need .htaccess to do that for the rest api stuff.
3. I moved subfolder to it's own domain because B is a wordpress website that is very much troubled. It changes its permissions and then the rest_api.php stops working. Moving it to another directory unhooks it from the word press directory and saves a lot of headache...
4. It works fine until I want it to just serve another file instead of a webpage...